# Conditional Formatting & Importrange using 2 spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, importrange

I am requiring specific cells of a Google spreadsheet to be conditionally formatted based on information in a different spreadsheet.

The information is input into `column J` of a spreadsheet titled 'Haulage' and in a worksheet with the same name. I then require any cell in the range `AE15:AH101` in a spreadsheet titled 'EMU Database' and in a worksheet titled '350' to be highlighted in a colour should the information in this cell match the information input into `column J` of the 'Haulage' spreadsheet/worksheet

ie '271' is in cell `AE15` of the worksheet '350' (in 'EMU Database' spreadsheet) and when I input the same value into cell `J3` of the worksheet 'Haulage' (in the 'Haulage' spreadsheet), AE15 is highlighted in the chosen colour.

I have tried using the following formula in the conditional formatting custom formula:

```
=A15=IMPORTRANGE("1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w",  "Haulage!J3:J")
```

But not been able to make it work unfortunately.

For reference, both of the spreadsheets have been linked together and access has been granted between the 2 spreadsheets

**Progress report:**

I have been playing around with the importrange options in making this conditional formatting work and I have managed to get it to work by importing the data into the same spreadsheet and then using a formula between worksheets as detailed below:

Data from "Haulage" spreadsheet and "Haulage" worksheet within this spreadsheet is transferred to "EMU Database", into a worksheet titled "Sheet5" using the standard importrange function. In the cells I require the custom formula to work I have then used the following custom formula:

```
=match(AE15,indirect("Sheet5!A1:A"),)
```

This offers a solution to my problem and works as I require it, however I would still like to find a solution to avoid having to transfer the data from one spreadsheet to another before the formula works. I have tried to amend the above formula in a number of ways to incorporate an IMPORTRANGE but without success. My most recent failing is below:

```
=match(AE15,indirect,importrange("1AGMJxw5D5TNFI19dvpPCT0Jl6QNu5rRX1bcLqHYJ0-w", "Haulage!J3:J"),)
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make the importrange work on this `match` formula it would be appreciated as it keeps things tidier for me than having extra worksheets with duplicate data from another spreadsheet

**Follow up information for @player0**

Links to the test versions of the relevant spreadsheets are below:

Haulage SS = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1elDxSOLSG-6U-jC6E5fgcKeJDNf9Kcu7GRGvK5p6fr4/edit?usp=sharing

EMU Database SS = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1poWzun1TvIhdlrHQyM_tSvJzEHFDpvZz7O-Ta0mvAR8/edit?usp=sharing

Within the "Haulage" spreadsheet, only the 'Haulage' worksheet is of interest - please disregard the other worksheet.

Within the "EMU Database" spreadsheet you will find my current conditional formatting in cell range `AE15:AO71` of worksheet '390'. This formatting is linked to the worksheet titled 'Sheet5' which contains the data that I have used the `importrange` formula (see cell A1 of this worksheet) to pull from cells `J3:J` of the Haulage spreadsheet.

Basically, what I require of the conditional formatting is for any data in cell range `AE15:AO71` of the '390' worksheet which matches data entered in cell range `J3:J` of the "Haulage" spreadsheet to be highlighted with a coloured box - but I want this to happen without the need for the extra worksheet with the imported data in

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=MATCH(A1, FILTER(
 IMPORTRANGE("1elDxSOLSG-6U-jC6E5fgcKeJDNf9Kcu7GRGvK5p6fr4", "Haulage!J3:J"), 
 IMPORTRANGE("1elDxSOLSG-6U-jC6E5fgcKeJDNf9Kcu7GRGvK5p6fr4", "Haulage!J3:J")<>""), 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid. Spent the last couple of hours playing around with variations of the formula you provided and nothing seems to be working. Even tried to import the data into the same spreadsheet and using ```=AE15=INDIRECT("Sheet5!A1:A")``` (and variations of this) and couldn't get that working properly (not that I really want to go down the route of importing data first)

Comment: I have made some progress with this @player0 - I have amended my original question to include this progress. If you can add anything to what I have done to make the importrange aspect work, it would be appreciated

Comment: did you authorize the importrange beforehand?

Comment: Providing you are referring to the requirement to 'allow access' I have indeed done this beforehand. This allowed me to import the data from the "Haulage" spreadsheet to the "EMU Database" spreadsheet. Am I right in thinking that this only needs to be done once to create a permanent link between 2 spreadsheets and allow importrange formulae to work?

Comment: yes, only once. can you share a copy of your sheets so I could cross-check where's the issue?

Comment: I have amended my original question to include further detail for you, including links to test versions of the relevant spreadsheets. I would prefer to give you the test versions to allow you the freedom to play around with it as much as you need to without the risk of losing data. Because of this, please note that some spreadsheet keys in these test sheets will differ from ones I have quoted previously - everything does work the same and these 2 test sheets are authorised to link data

Comment: That certainly works for data that is already logged in the "Haulage" spreadsheet, however it doesn't seem to work when I either add or remove data from it. Still using the test spreadsheets I linked you to, I have added your formula to cell range ```AE15:AE17``` in the '350' worksheet of "EMU Database" ss. As you will see I have added and removed data in the ```J``` column of the "Haulage" spreadsheet and the data now doesn't correlate with what is highlighted within the conditional formatting of the '350' worksheet